# Cannot unlock Users & Group in System Preferences

Tags: high-sierra

I was making some changes recently, trying to rename my user account from within macOS High Sierra System Preferences, and it seems I've locked myself out from making any changes to Users & Groups now.

When I click the lock icon (Click the lock to make changes) I am prompted for a Username and Password. No matter what I input in these fields I am unable to unlock the preferences. I am sure I know my user account, otherwise I wouldn't be able to log into the computer, and there is only 1 user on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

That fix is actually simpler than you might think, though it does call for a reboot, two if you want to be technical.

1. Reboot your Mac while holding <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> This will boot you into recovery mode.
2. From the Utilities menu select Terminal
3. type `resetpassword` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. The password reset utility will launch. Follow the prompts to reset your password.

Comment: its not like that I forgot my password I do remember my password but any how its not working. and they are not showing my ac as admin its showing as standard ac

Comment: That is what that procedure is for. The system got your password messed up, that should "un-mess" it. Try it and report back, if it didn't work jot down any and all error messages and edit your original question with the results.

Comment: I did the procedure as mentioned. its change my user password but still dose not allow me to login in user and group system preference.

Comment: Create a new Admin user, log out of your current one and log in as the new one you just created. If you can make the changes there then something in your profile is messed up. Best to just migrate your data to the new Profile and delete the old one.